# SharePoint 2013 search results should exclude sites home/landing pages, except for one

Tags: search, search-results

I need my search results to exclude all Home/landing pages from search since these are displayed in the global navigation.  However, I have one site that isn't in the global navigation and I would therefore like it to appear in the search results.

So far I've managed to get the results source to exclude home pages by using IsContainer<>true. How do I make an exception to this rule, in order for me to display my 'Locations' home/landing page (featured on the site that isn't in the global navigation)?

Answer (score 0):

I personally just use a bool, which I check on all site pages, I then exclude all site pages in the refiner part of the search result snippet.

For example.  I have - `IsSitePage`, this bool is checked for all site pages that should be ignored by search.

Under Search Results snippet query, I select refiner, scroll down to the `IsSitePage` property and select no.  This automatically removes any site pages from the results.